# VPN-over-Tor in Tails. How? It always fails for me

Tags: tails, proxy, vpn, openvpn

I need VPN-over-Tor because I need to be able to access some websites that block access from Tor. As far as I know, the only other alternative is always using the unsafe browser for those websites, but that's really not ideal.

I have tried to follow this tutorial about VPN-over-Tor: https://exposingtheinvisible.org/guides/vpn-over-tor

Is that tutorial still up to date? I can't find when it was written. It's very nicely written with a lot of details.

I tried to follow that tutorial, but when I try to run the script, it fails. The main problem seems to be that it fails connecting to the local tor proxy:

```
`TCP: connect to [AF_INET]`[`127.0.0.1:9053`](https://127.0.0.1:9053) `failed: Connection refused`
```

This is the full log:

```
amnesia@amnesia:~$ sudo ~/Persistent/bin/vot.sh

[sudo] password for amnesia:

********************** reloading firewall to apply rules for VPN **********************

​

[....] Reloading ferm configuration (via systemctl): ferm.serviceJob for ferm.service failed.

See "systemctl status ferm.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

failed!

​

​

********************** restarting Tor **********************

​

​

​

********************** waiting for Tor to be ready **********************

​

​

​

********************** starting OpenVPN **********************

​

*****************************************************************************************

* remember: to use the VPN connection you MUST start software as user "vpnuser", like *

* "sudo -u vpnuser MySoftware" or "gksu -u vpnuser MySoftware" *

* *

* for software integrated in Tails be aware that it will be configured to use Tor proxy *

* you'll need to reconfigure and/or user additional software *

*****************************************************************************************

​

​

Thu Apr 30 23:22:43 2020 OpenVPN 2.4.7 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Feb 20 2019

Thu Apr 30 23:22:43 2020 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1d 10 Sep 2019, LZO 2.10

Thu Apr 30 23:22:59 2020 NOTE: starting with OpenVPN 2.1, '--script-security 2' or higher is required to call user-defined scripts or executables

Thu Apr 30 23:22:59 2020 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:9053

Thu Apr 30 23:22:59 2020 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:9053 [nonblock]

Thu Apr 30 23:23:01 2020 TCP: connect to [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:9053 failed: Connection refused

Thu Apr 30 23:23:01 2020 NOTE: chroot will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay

Thu Apr 30 23:23:01 2020 NOTE: UID/GID downgrade will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay

Thu Apr 30 23:23:01 2020 SIGUSR1[connection failed(soft),init_instance] received, process restarting

Thu Apr 30 23:23:06 2020 NOTE: starting with OpenVPN 2.1, '--script-security 2' or higher is required to call user-defined scripts or executables

Thu Apr 30 23:23:06 2020 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:9053

Thu Apr 30 23:23:06 2020 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:9053 [nonblock]

Thu Apr 30 23:23:08 2020 TCP: connect to [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:9053 failed: Connection refused

Thu Apr 30 23:23:08 2020 SIGUSR1[connection failed(soft),init_instance] received, process restarting
```

Any help with getting this to work is super appreciated. Thanks!